# Bash - limit subshells in recursion

Tags: bash, recursion

I decided to test recursions in bash on my production server.

**Don't run this code on a  production machine!**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function fibo {
    if [ $1 -le 1 ]; then
        echo $1
    else
        echo $((
            $( fibo $(( $1 - 1 )) ) +
            $( fibo $(( $1 - 2 )) )
        ))
    fi
}

fibo 100
```

I suspected it will be slow, however, did not expect it will run tens of parallel jobs.
I was thinking that because the server is multicore, I would be able to kill the process.

Unfortunately, the server froze and from the hosting company restarted it.

Is there a way to limit the parallel jobs in bash?

Is it possible to set the PID of the main process in a timer and to stop all the child jobs?

Of course, am asking for academic purposes only.

**Edit**

The **Tail recursion** version works like a charm:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

fibo() {
    local n=$1 a=$2 b=$3

    case $n in
        0) echo "$a" ;;
        1) echo "$b" ;;
        *) fibo $((n - 1)) "$b" $((a + b)) ;;
    esac
}

fibo "${1:-10}" 0 1
```

Benchmark:

```
time ./fibotr.sh 100

3736710778780434371

real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: You can absolutely use `ulimit`s to limit number of processes, though that (like other OS-level configuration) is more a [unix.se] question than a Stack Overflow one.

Comment: Any time you use `$(...)`, that's forking off a new process -- but you don't _need_ to write your code with `$(...)`!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know I can use the return code, but hoped to go over the 256 limits?

Comment: Re: stopping all the children on a timer, you can kill your process group, but that's only if you can get scheduled. The nature of a fork bomb is that it's overwhelming the scheduler.

Comment: (...so, if you _are_ to take that approach, using `renice` to drop your priority level in the children helps to make it more likely that the parent can get some cycles when it needs them; still, I'd prefer a PID limit to a timed process-group kill).

Comment: BTW, I didn't think you were asking how to write an efficient copy of `fibo` in bash -- the question as originally asked was about how to limit subshells, and that original question is what I answered. Is there anything that makes that answer unacceptable as presently written?

Answer (score 1):

As for prevention methods, see our sister site [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Among the topical questions they have in place is [Executing a fork bomb safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167795/executing-a-fork-bomb-safely).

As an implementation of your original algorithm that doesn't fork off any subshells at all, and thus can't possibly turn into a fork bomb even when passed arbitrarily large numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -g _fibo_resA _fibo_resB # be explicit that it's intentional that these
                                 # variables aren't locals, for future readers
fibo() {
    local _fibo_outvar _fibo_inVal _fibo_locResA _fibo_locResB
    _fibo_outvar=$1; _fibo_inVal=$2
    if [ "$_fibo_inVal" -le 1 ]; then
        printf -v "$_fibo_outvar" 1
    else
        fibo _fibo_resA "$(( _fibo_inVal - 1 ))"; _fibo_locResA=$_fibo_resA
        fibo _fibo_resB "$(( _fibo_inVal - 2 ))"; _fibo_locResB=$_fibo_resB
        printf -v "$_fibo_outvar" "$(( _fibo_locResA + _fibo_locResB ))"
    fi
}

# note that 100 is way too big; performance breaks down between 20 and 30
# but at least it won't act like a fork bomb!
fibo result "${1:-100}"  # let user pass in a value they choose
echo "$result"
```

Why is this written the way it is?

- The most important change was to eliminate `$( )`, but this requires no longer passing output up to the parent on stdout. Hence, using [indirect assignments](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables) for the purpose.
- Use of namespaced variable names (even for locals!) prevents conflicts when returning a result by-name: If the user chose to write a result to a variable name that matched any of our locals, their value would be written to the local, not the global variable they want their result placed in.
- `locResA` and `locResB` are used because we aren't forking and can't make `resA` and `resB` local; they prevent other copies of `fibo` from overwriting the results before we're able to return them.
- The `funcname() {` syntax declaration form is used because `function funcname {` is a ksh-ism. In ksh, however, this format changes behavior of code within the block; bash does not honor that intent. Consequently, using POSIX-compliant `funcname() {` has less surprises for folks coming from a ksh background, *and* improves your code's compatibility with other POSIX shells; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (note that function declaration syntax is mentioned in more than one place).